# Makefiles in java with multiple dirrectories and dependencies

Tags: java, makefile, circular-dependency

So the program that I have created in Java has grown to the point where I need to start putting code in other directories to keep it more organized. The problem that I keep running into is trying to get two classes that are dependent upon each other to compile while they are in different directories. The name of the two folders are `Items` and `Animals`. The Item folder holds various different subclasses of `Item` and `Animals` is likewise. The `Item` has an owner who is an `Animal` and the `Animal` has a list of `Items`.
I found that in Java I can use:

```
set CLASSPATH=./Animal;./Items
#or 
Javac -classpath ./Animal;./Items <list classes>
```

so I tried to call both when `Player` only needed `Animal` and `Animal` needed `Items` and `Items` need `Animal`. The part of the make file being affected I have this:

```
Player.class: Animal.jar Items.jar
    #do Player compiling stuff
Animal.jar: ./Animal/*.java
    set CLASSPATH=./AIEngine;./Animal;./Items;./
    javac ./Animal/*.java
    jar cvfe Animal.jar ./Animal/*.class

Items.jar: ./Items/*.java
    set CLASSPATH=./AIEngine;./Animal;./Items;./
    javac ./Items/*.java
    jar cvfe Items.jar ./Items/*.class
```

But either `Items` complain that it can't find `Animal` or `Animal` complains it can't find `Items`.

Comment: Have you looked at [Maven](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Tutorial%3A+Build+a+JAR+file+with+Maven+in+5+minutes) or [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)?

Comment: I suggest using a build tool designed for Java.

Comment: I would suggest using an IDE that will do all of this for you. Then when you need to worry about packaging and deployment, you could move to a build tool.